# SSH access to router via inband and OOB ports

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, ssh, cisco-nexus

I am aware of management VRF where inband port and OOB port on router can be part of and support SSH access to the router from both management port and network port.

In this case inband port(network port) cant be used for data plane forwarding as it is part of management VRF. How can I configure a network port in cisco NEXUS where it allows SSH access and also support Data plane forwarding ?

```
         (mgmt-port)ROUTER-01(network port) ========== (ROUTER-02) ====
```

So in the above topology i want to SSH into ROUTER-01 via network port instead of management port.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the model or NX-OS version, but you should be able to SSH into an inband ethernet interface which has been configured for layer-3 and addressed. You will find the following in the Cisco documentation for 5K, 7K, and 9K Nexus switches, e.g. [Cisco Nexus 7000 Series NX-OS Security Configuration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/4_1/nx-os/security/configuration/guide/sec_nx-os-cfg/sec_ssh.html):

> ### Prerequisites for SSH
>
> SSH and Telnet have the following prerequisites:
>
> - You have configured IP on a Layer 3 interface, out-of-band on the    mgmt 0 interface, or inband on an Ethernet interface.